# How to assign an input value as comparison parameter to the Selection filter in thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to filter a Collection using thymeleaf Projection/selection feature.

```
<tr   th:each = "c: ${Clients.?[firstName >='myParameter']}"  >
......
</tr>
```

However I like to  set the value of "myParameter" from an input value instead of fixed value. 
 thank you for your collaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `myParameter` using the special object `#root`.  This will work:

```
<tr th:each="c: ${Clients.?[firstName GE #root.myParameter]}">
    <td th:text="${c.firstName}" />
    <td th:text="${c.lastName}" />
</tr>
```